# Populate new MovieClip() with JSON object properties

Tags: actionscript-3

I have saved out an object using JSON.encode to a text file, is it possible to then create a new MovieClip and populate it with all of the properties from the saved file? If so how would it be done, or is there a better way, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very possible.

Check out [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/). It has some very nice JSON utilities. Then you can do something like:

```
var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader('pathToText/json.js');

//load
var things:Array = JSON.decode( loader.data );
for(var i:int = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
  for(var j:int = 0; j < things[i].length; j++) {
    trace(things[i][j].property);
  }
}
```

That being said, I think XML is [really easy to use in AS3](http://www.flashblog.co.uk/actionscript-basics-reading-xml-tutorial/), and I generally prefer it when working with flash (for modest data sets, anyhow).

Comment: glad it helps. Interestingly, I feel the exact opposite when working with javascript. JSON is way easier. Its all about the dot syntax. Cheers. Nice website, btw.

Comment: Thanks! I am now using XML for storing my data which really helps but now the Flash ADL is stuck in portrait when my app is in landscape mode WTF!